# Affine Transforms + Demo App

Tags: ios, uiimage, cgaffinetransform

I have a demo app here https://github.com/rdetert/image-transform-test

After importing an image, you can pinch, zoom, rotate the image. What I want to do is save out a `640x480` image (landscape mode) that looks identical to the live preview. So if there are 100px bars of empty space on the sides, I need the same empty bars in the final output (scaled appropriately).

This is proving to be more difficult than I thought it would be. I can't quite get it to come out right after days of working on it.

The magic method that generates the final image is called `-(void)generateFinalImage`

Good luck! ;)

**EDIT**

[image: Demo App Screenshot]

The green rectangle represents the actual area the imported image can be pinched, zoomed and rotated. The resolution on the iPhone 4S is 852x640, for example.

The blue rectangle is just a live preview for debugging and it's aspect ratio is the same as 640x480. The live preview could get very slow due to Core Image being very slow.

What I want to do is convert whatever is in the green rectangle to a `640x480` image. Notice the `852x640` is a slightly different aspect ratio than `640x480` too, but that isn't a huge problem.

Comment: I am not sure, what you are exactly about to solve. Opening the app I could see an image or part above your button. So the area above the button is your source area, modified, pinched or what ever applied to. Should this area be scaled into 640x480?

Comment: @iOS I have updated the question, please let me know if it needs to be more clear.

Comment: Mark is right if you want to get a copy of what is beeing seen, you should not rely on the imported image and its dimensions. If you take a snapshot of the 'edited' image as an input it could be easily solved.

Comment: Am I misunderstanding the point of this? The green rectangle shows an image which you can scale, rotate etc, and the blue rectangle shows... The same thing, but smaller? (Note I haven't downloaded the project, but the requirement should be obvious from the question, really)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your goal is to obtain just the exact copy of what you are editing, but with the size of the original image? 
I guess it could be obtained by something like this:

```
- (UIImage *)padImage:(UIImage *)img to:(CGSize)size
{
    if (size.width < img.size.width && size.height < img.size.height) return img;

    size.width = MAX(size.width, img.size.width);
    size.height = MAX(size.height, img.size.height);

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, size.width, size.height, 8, 0, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);

    CGRect centeredRect = CGRectMake((size.width - img.size.width)/2.0, (size.height - img.size.height)/2.0, img.size.width, img.size.height);
    CGContextDrawImage(context, centeredRect, [img CGImage]);

    CGImageRef imageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);

    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
    CGContextRelease(context);

    UIImage *paddedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    return paddedImage;
}

// final image size must be 640x480
- (void)generateFinalImage
{
    float rotatableCanvasWidth = 495.0;
    float rotatableCanvasHeight = 320.0;
    UIImage *tmp = self.importedRawImage;

    CGSize size = self.importedRawImage.size;
    NSLog(NSStringFromCGSize(size));

    tmp = [self padImage:tmp to:CGSizeMake(rotatableCanvasWidth, rotatableCanvasHeight)];
    CIImage *ciImage = [[CIImage alloc] initWithImage:[tmp imageWithTransform:self.importedImageView.transform]];

    CGPoint center = CGPointMake(size.width / 2.0, size.height / 2.0);

    CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
    CGRect r = ciImage.extent;
    r.origin.x = (r.size.width - rotatableCanvasHeight) / 2.0;
    r.origin.y = (r.size.height - rotatableCanvasWidth) / 2.0;
    r.size.width = rotatableCanvasHeight;
    r.size.height = rotatableCanvasWidth;
    self.finalImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[context createCGImage:ciImage fromRect:r] scale:1.0 orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];

    self.finalImage = [self.finalImage resizedImage:CGSizeMake(100.0f, 134.0f) interpolationQuality:kCGInterpolationHigh];

    self.previewImageView.image = self.finalImage;
}
```

Comment: @ACB yes I think it should be, a value of 495 causes stretching. Not sure where 495 comes from or why the +/- 4.0 is there either.

Comment: @MarkPervovskiy This is very close. The goal is to get an exact copy of what is being edited on the screen. I said `640x480` originally, but that is silly, it should just be what is on the screen. There is one other thing with this code you've posted, try using a smaller image (e.g. 256x256) Then move the image around. You'll see that it clips strangely in the image preview.

Comment: @ACB, I've downloaded the project and the visible size of editing area is 990*640, so I used 495*320 ... If you have (by any reason) other size - you should adjust this values.

Comment: I guess, the easiest way is to pad original image before transform. Edited source code in my answer

Comment: I've checked in new code with your edits as well as one other workaround. When scaling the image smaller, the same problem was happening, so I've worked around it by building off your code. There is one last thing: Assuming landscape orientation, when moving the image up and down, the final image seems to be correct at the edges, however when moving left to right, if you move the image to the edge of the screen, there is still a noticeable gap in the final image. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand correctly, but if I did - `float rotatableCanvasWidth = self.importedImageView.bounds.size.height;
    float rotatableCanvasHeight = self.importedImageView.bounds.size.width;` should help, I think you are using wrong width.

Comment: +1. Almost perfect. Only problem is if I select an image and zoom out to make it very small and then move around still that issue is there with edges getting cut off. I have copy pasted the rotatableCanvasWidth and rotatableCanvasHeight change mentioned in the above comment but still getting this. Any idea?

Comment: @ACB, get the new code from git and cannot reproduce the bug... may be you should do a little more padding?

Comment: One more thing I just realized. The images are saving based on Point size (so about 407x320). I want to save in pixels (814x640). Any idea?

Comment: As far as I can see, a) if you save result image - you receive the same image as on the view b) the size of original image still the same (if you are not resizing it), so the changing size of the result image will violate one of this requirements. As far as I understand, the image loaded to UIImageView automatically resized to look good on Retina screen, but it is not changing its actual size. Think about it – your app (theoretically, at least) can work on Retina screens and non-Retina screens, but I guess you do not want to receive your image twice as large in all dimensions in the first case